# Azure Logic apps on Sharepoint

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard, azure-blob-trigger

"I am unable to transfer files from Blob to SharePoint using a Logic App workflow. I have attempted to create a workflow, but after getting blob contents, it states 'moved secure content not found.' However, I was able to send an email using a Logic App that had blob content. I am having difficulty transferring blob content to SharePoint. Please see the attached image for reference."

[image]

The above image can help understand things

Comment: I don’t know what that action is that you’re using but it doesn’t look right to me. Where are you wanting to move the file to? A document library or list item?

Comment: I do agree with @Skin, you need to use SharePoint Connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to transfer files from Blob to SharePoint using a Logic App workflow.

Below is the **`design`** which works for me:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

In SharePoint:

[image]

Comment: can you please specify the parameters you give for get blob content as iam getting errors

Comment: Sure @Anjumaara, https://i.imgur.com/b0tdlzs.png

Comment: @Anjumaara, Glad that the Solution worked!!